# D3.js Stacked Bar Chart, from vertical to horizontal

Tags: d3.js, charts, stacked-chart

I like to make this vertical Bar Chart (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208) to a horizontal Bar Chart.

Thanks for your help!

Code examples would be nice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's just a matter of reversing the domains, axis and then the rect calculations:

```
var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([height, 0], .1); // y becomes ordinal

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .rangeRound([0, width]); // x becomes linear

// change state group to be positioned in the y now instead of x
var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(0," + y(d.State) + ")"; });

// rect calculations become
 state.selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("height", y.rangeBand()) // height in now the rangeband
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.y0); }) // this is the horizontal position in the stack
    .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.y1) - x(d.y0); }) // this is the horizontal "height" of the bar
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
```

Here's the full working [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y33oYNB9de9xiq1pnl0Q?p=preview).

Comment: I like to add two features: first: bar label inside the bars and second: x axis a time scale with this data input: State, int, ext
AL,00:13:00,00:16:02
AK,00:20:03,0
AZ,00:58:52,0
AR,00:45:30,00:17:39
CA,0,00:54:08
CO,00:35:01,0
CT,0,00:03:39